# Create new document with refs and supplying them with objectIds in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to use mongoose create function to create a new document that contains refs and i want to supply those objectsIds for those refs but i am getting an error and i cant seem to figure it out how to make it work. I tried to search for an answer but without any luck.

I have the following model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const messageSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    providerId: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Provider'
    }],
    accountId: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Account'
    }],
    conversationId: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Conversation'
    }],
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['provider', 'account'],
      default: 'provider',
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['queued', 'sent'],
      default: 'queued',
    },
    sendAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now()
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

/**
 * @typedef Message
 */
const Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);

module.exports = Message;
```

And have the following code for the creation:

```
const prevMessage = await Message.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: match[1] },
    { $set: { status: placement.toLowerCase() } },
    {
        upsert: true,
        new: true
    }
).exec();

const document = {
    providerId: { "$oid": prevMessage.providerId[0] },
    accountId: { "$oid": prevMessage.accountId[0] },
    conversationId: { "$oid": prevMessage.conversationId[0] },
    type: "provider",
    status: "queued",
    sendAt: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 15 * 60000),
}

Message.create(document, { w: 1 }, function (err, res) {
    if (err) return logger.error(err);

    console.log(res);
})
```

The prevMessage object looks as following:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("62590640993fcbb2027aa521"),
  type: 'provider',
  status: 'sent',
  updatedAt: 2022-04-18T16:31:11.483Z,
  accountId: [ new ObjectId("623ccc5faa4d1a000cd1c608") ],
  conversationId: [ new ObjectId("625be027993fcbb202a6e682") ],
  createdAt: 2022-03-25T20:11:40.000Z,
  providerId: [ new ObjectId("625a97ff993fcbb202af92ee") ],
  sendAt: 2022-03-25T20:11:40.000Z
}
```

The error that i get is the following:

```
error: ValidationError: Message validation failed: providerId.0: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "`[ { '$oid': new ObjectId("625a97ff993fcbb202af92ee") } ]`" (type string) at path "providerId.0", accountId.0: 
Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "`[ { '$oid': new ObjectId("623ccc5faa4d1a000cd1c608") } ]`" (type string) at path "accountId.0", conversationId.0: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "`[ { '$oid': new ObjectId("625be027993fcbb202a6e682") } ]`" (type string) at path "conversationId.0"
```

If anyone can help cause i cant figure it out how to create this document with refs that should an objectId value.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution right after 5 mins i posted this.

The error was that i wanted to add the values of refs as $oid, but the solution was to simply use:

```
providerId: prevMessage.providerId[0]
```